# Nested Json response to csv conversion

Tags: apex, integration, json, csv

I got this response from API however I couldn't be able to parse name because of the nested objects, example this is my query trying fetch `permissionSetAssignmen`t records from one org to other in salesforce

Query:

```
select Id, PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name, Assignee.Name,Assignee.Profile.name, Assignee.FederationIdentifier from PermissionSetAssignment
```

class to deserialize http response

```apex
if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                String str = res.getBody();
                SalesforceConnectWrapper wr = (SalesforceConnectWrapper)JSON.deserialize(str, SalesforceConnectWrapper.class);
                
                system.debug(wr);
```

Response :

```json
(records:[Assignee=cls_Assignee:[Email=noreply@chatter.salesforce.com, FederationIdentifier=null, Name=Chatter Expert], Id=0Pa5g000004wvWcCAI, PermissionSetId=0PS5g0000097iIbGAI, PermissionSetName=null, Profile=null], records:[Assignee=cls_Assignee:[Email=noreply@example.com, FederationIdentifier=null, Name=Integration User], Id=0Pa5g000004wvWdCAI, PermissionSetId=0PS5g0000097iIfGAI, PermissionSetName=null, Profile=null], records:[Assignee=cls_Assignee:[Email=noreply@example.com, FederationIdentifier=null, Name=Security User], Id=0Pa5g000004wvWeCAI, PermissionSetId=0PS5g0000097iIeGAI, PermissionSetName=null, Profile=null], records:[Assignee=cls_Assignee:[Email=praveen@test.com, FederationIdentifier=null, Name=Praveen Patil], Id=0Pa5g000004wvWhCAI, PermissionSetId=0PS5g0000097iI4GAI, PermissionSetName=null, Profile=null])
```

how to I store those values in the for of csv and send out an email?

Appreciate all your help! Thanks

Comment: Deserilaizng _before_ debugging makes the output significantly less useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make things harder on yourself than they need to be. Use an appropriate wrapper class that just handles the record deserialization for you.

```
class sObjectQueryResult {
    sObject[] records;
    Boolean done;
    Integer totalSize;
    String nextRecordsUrl;
}
```

Then, you can deserialize any kind of graph into native code:

```
String str = res.getBody();
sObjectQueryResult result = (sObjectQueryResult)JSON.deserialize(str, sObjectQueryResult.class);
```

As Adrian pointed out, don't rely on System.debug printing out all the useful information, because it won't.

Finally, to access the records, remember this class won't know the type of sObject directly, so you need to cast from the top level:

```
PermissionSetAssignment psa = (PermissionSetAssignment)result.records[0];
System.debug(psa.PermissionSet.Name);
System.debug(psa.Assignee.Name);
// ... etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Just seeing 1 error on this line : PermissionSetAssignment psa = (PermissionSetAssignment)result.records[0];

Error: "Variable is not visible: sObjectQueryResult.records"

sorry to bother you! I'm new to salesforce

Comment: @PraveenPatil That was written as an "Inner Class"; if you write this as a separate class entirely, make the properties `public`.

Comment: Great! 

I was trying to get it from another wrapper apex class with public property only but that didn't work for some reason. 

This solution helped! Thank you so much for the help :)